# Все поля null в моём модуле

Tags: android

Сохранил app как модуль и пытаюсь запустить активность(или фрагмент) в другом `app`. Но почти все поля возвращают `null`. Суть проблемы сделать из действующего `app` модуль чтобы можно было использовать даную активность или фрагмент в другом приложении. Есть идеи? Спасибо.

Оригинальная активность:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnFlip  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFlip);
        btnQrCode  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnQr);
```

как я ее запускаю в новом app:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, com.android.sliderview.MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

Но получаю null, она выглядит в модуле при дебаге:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(layout.activity_main);
        this.btnFlip = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(id.btnFlip); // btnFlip: null
        this.btnQrCode = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(id.btnQr); // btnQrCode: null
```

Comment: Слой по другому назовите.

Comment: И!!!!!! ЭТО правельный ответ! Этот парень получает медаль! Спасибо! Столько промучался, а делов то! Но почему так? Конфликт? СЕНКС!

Comment: Сложно сказать. Я б ожидал, что ошибка будет. Странно, что оно не выдаёт предупреждений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорей всего activity_main слой из приложения перекрывает activity_main из модуля.

Надо переименовать.